# replacing the superfluous 'innerHTML' with something else. Javascript

Tags: javascript

im looking for a replacement for .innerHTML.. something that can also clear the div and replace it with a string of code i have..
the problem with innerhtml is that it forces me to use superfluous code (anyone know why?) // AND i can't seem to break `'<br>` more than once in a line..

ive tried search for an answer but cant find any.  any help is appreciated.

Comment: What superfluous code? Best make some concrete examples of what doesn't work for you.

Comment: Why not try a framework like jQuery? http://api.jquery.com

Comment: Don't get what you mean "superfluous".  Also CLOSE YOUR TAGS! `<br />`

Comment: @endophage `<element />` notation is an obsolete relic of XHTML and should not be used in new pages.

Comment: @Zack having unclosed tags still breaks some parsers.

Comment: Here's a nickel, kid, go get yourself a [HTML5 parser](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/).

Comment: @Zack Here's a dime: Corporate standards.

Comment: @Endophage 1. BR is an empty element, ergo, it cannot be closed. `<br>` is fine. 2. Unclosed tags break some parsers? I doubt that. Empty elements have been around for ages (and before XHTML came along). `<br>` should not break any parser.

Comment: @Zack Well, `<element />` notation is required if you want your page to be a valid XHTML document.

Comment: @Zack Let me put it this way.  Across all the web standards `<br />` is valid.  It may be deprecated, it may only be in the specification to support old code but it's valid.  `<br>` can't claim that same compatibility.

Comment: @Šime: Precisely, an obsolete requirement.

Comment: @Zack XHMTL is not obsolete. I believe HTML 5 allows XHTML syntax. BTW I'm in the HTML camp, but I'm just saying ... `:)`

Comment: @Endophage That's not true. `<br />` is not valid in the HTML 4 standard (and every other HTML standard except HTML 5 I believe). Also, you say that `<br>` is not that compatible? You mean with browsers?

Comment: @Šime Meh... fair enough.  I have to write my markup to XHTML 1.0 specs so I'm going to keep closing my tags.  And in terms of being obsolete, the XHTML 1.0 specification was initially released in 2000 and was last updated November 2010 to v1.1.  HTML 4.01 was released in 1999 and hasn't been updated.  Now @Zack tell me which is more obsolete.

Comment: The XHTML working group has been *disbanded*.  See http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/ and note well "This *was* the home page", the pointer to the HTML WG, the red box, and the top entry in the news area.  Furthermore, no web browser vendor (except possibly Opera) has paid serious attention to the XHTML WG for at least five years.  I stand on my assertion that XHTML is obsolete.

Comment: @Zack that's the XHTML2 working group.  So there won't be an XHTML2 specification.  That doesn't mean the previous version is obsolete.  Would you say Windows XP is obsolete because there are 2 newer releases of Windows?  It's still the most widely used OS with ~47%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [jQuery.](http://jquery.com/)

```
  $('#myDiv').replaceWith(whatever);
```

that will replace the entirety of that DOM element with whatever you put in it's place..

```
$('#myDiv').html(whatever);
```

that will retain the DOM element while replacing all of the contents of the div in the same way innerHTML does.

```
$('#myDiv').append(whatever);
```

that will retain the DOM element AND it's content and add your content onto the BACK of that element.

```
$('#myDiv').prepend(whatever);
```

that will retain the DOM element AND it's content and add your content onto the FRONT of that element.

Comment: Amazing. Just mention jQuery and you'll get votes, even though the code is wrong, and we don't know the actual issue OP has.

Comment: It's `replaceWith`, not `replace`

Comment: @Šime Vidas Thanks. missed that.

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by superfluous, it is pretty straightforward. Check it out http://jsfiddle.net/s8ajC/.

```
<div id="test">some content</div>

<script>
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'some<br />content<br />and more';
</script>
```

Comment: Well I'm not sure what the question really is, but +1 for a good demonstration of innerHTML.

Comment: All these years later, you are still helping people.